# Unable to upload file stored on my windows machine using Selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, image-uploading, browser-automation

I am unable to upload a file to a website using selenium python,
My code runs well till Clicking the upload button and opening the Windows file browser frame.
sendkeys doesnot work
AutoIT doesnot work
How do i use this. I tried it but it doesnot works?

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_‌​keys(filepath)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/path/Downloads/path/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://abc.xys")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("id_username")
elem.send_keys(user)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password")
elem.send_keys(pwd)`enter code here`
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
Upload_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button").send_keys(r'''C:\Users\path\Pictures\test22.jpg''')
```

I expect the image file to be uploaded

Comment: The `.send_keys` method is for your `webdriver` I believe. The script you wrote only connects to chromium. Once you go to your windows dialog box, that's `winauto32` already? that's why `.send_keys` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I found the Upload button element using the path but i am stuck after that

Comment: Yes, exactly, because opening the dialog box is out of chromium already. `Selenium` only controls your chromium. So I suggest explore `pyautogui` as well to type on that dialog box and click upload?

Comment: I tried driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button").send_keys(os.getcwd()+r'''C:\Users\path\Pictures\test22.jpg''')..doesnot helps

Comment: `.send_keys()` only works on `input` webelements. Modify your xpath such that it points to the input element of your upload text box.

Comment: @GPT14 i tried this : browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_‌​keys(filepath)..didnt work either

Comment: can you try with forward slashes / or double backward slashes \\ in your file path? eg: `"C:\\Users\\path\\Pictures\\test22.jpg"`